# Shell script comparison does not work as intended

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The following  code is supposed to compare two strings or variables. But, I cannot do it. Here, output doesn't depend upon the changing of inputs. Can anyone correct this code?

```
#!/bin/sh  
echo "Enter your username1:"  
read username1  
echo "Enter your username2:"  
read useraname2  
if [ "$username1"=="$username2" ]  
then  
echo 'Same'  
else  
echo 'Different'  
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick fix: add spaces around `==`

The `[` command does different things depending on how many arguments it receives. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test

When given 1 argument, the test command evaluates to true if the argument is a non-empty string. In your case that is guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: Should also mention that `==` is not a standard operator for the `[` command. In bash, `==` is treated the same as `=`, but for sh, only `=` is defined to work.